# No User can access 'setup' in Marketing Org

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a Marketing Org. It has a single Business Unit. By mistake, if someone has changed the roles of a business unit such that this unit cannot access the 'setup'. In this case, can anyone access the 'setup'?

Comment: Same thing has happened to two orgs I administer lately. In my case, my users had been assigned _all_ roles for some inexplicable reason. Support could fix this by reverting the roles back to "admin" & "marketing cloud admin" roles only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically - yes. But you can raise a ticket with Support, and they can change the role accordingly.

According to [this guide](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_marketing_cloud_roles.htm&type=5), which is good to know, an explicit **Deny** will always overrule an explicit **Allow**. Regardless if one is set on a user role and another on a BU role:

> An explicitly denied permission always overrides all other
>   permissions. When a permission is not explicitly granted or denied,
>   Marketing Cloud defaults to a deny permission unless another role
>   grants that permission.